# Can I allow standard user to give permission for a single software to auto-update?

Tags: permissions, administrator, uac, software-update, standard-user

I will be very specific, but the question could relate to any software...

Sage 50 (formerly Peachtree Accounting), like many software, uses third-party utilities for some of its functions. The one in particular that I need help with is Aatrix Forms. Every time you generate forms in Sage 50 for tax filings, the Aatrix software connects to the server to see if there are any updates to the tax forms. However, in order to download these latest forms, UAC kicks in and requires an administrative privilege.

How can I allow a standard user to run this software without having to call an Administrator every day to come in and allow them to print a simple form? Ideally, I'd like to allow Aatrix to download and install the latest forms on its own, but I, by no means, want a standard user to be able to update the entire Sage 50 software.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the software (Sage in your case), then you can set up Task Scheduler to update the software.  Ask Sage for a command line to run the update.

In the credentials sections, run the task with highest elevation and give the task Admin Credentials. This will allow standard users to run the software update.

Set it to run at Windows Startup.

The above works for me.

Otherwise, standard users cannot update software that requires Admin Credentials.

[image: Windows Task Scheduler to run Admin Task]

Comment: I don't want Sage to update. I want Aatrix Forms to update which is launched from a Sage task.

Comment: Ask Sage for a command line for Aatrix Forms.  The process I gave you is a standard process for running a Task with Admin Credentials.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but the problem is that Aatrix Forms checks for updates every time it is launched. So, even if I updated it on startup with admin permissions, it would still attempt to update when the standard user attempted to print forms.

Comment: Try to find out the Aatrix Form update command to update it via Task Manager. That should be able to do it before launching.

Comment: Just so you know, Task Scheduler is is no way unique to Sage. It is used all over the place in Windows to manage software that the standard user cannot.